# Electron-Forge unable to publish to nucleus or github

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-forge

As the title states, currently im trying to publish an electron app to either github or my nucleus server and am unable to and have been plagued by errors for the last 8 hours. Currently the error im getting is

"could not find a publish target with the name: @electron-forge/publisher-github"

I get the same thing except with "publisher-nucleus" when i attempt to use my nucleus server. I have attempted reinstalling electron and electron-forge, creating a new project with init and no progress has been made.

any help is appreciated.